# How to display prices in offers tables?

Tags: tables, ux-designer, pricing

I am working on displaying offers (consisting of 3 - 4 plans) in table style and am currently stuck in showing the prices. I was working on showing offers per column / vertically with having the price at the bottom of the offer as it's not eCommerce and only an informative site. I also believe that this display will be convenient for browsing the offers on a mobile responsive view. (Offer 1 in attached photo)

Saying this, I found another offer that has multiple items (around 8 items) and I find it better to display them horizontally. (Offer 2 in attached photo)
[image]

My question is, how can I unify both displays no matter the number of the items in order not to confuse users?

Answer (score 1):

There are several ways

### Carousel

[image]

### Rows

Selectable rows with hidden info which can be displayed in full screen after pressing the <kbd>View more</kbd> icon:

[image: rows]

### Cards

[image: cards]